# How to authenticate microsoft graph api?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

Am trying to configure the graphseviceclient to get the outlook calendar events of other user in the same organization.Here am using the below code in program.cs,

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "OutlookEvents",
        Version = "v1"
    });

    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
        {
            Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("xxx"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri("xxx"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
               {
                  "api://xxx/xxx",
                  "xxx"
               }
             
            }
            }
    }
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement() {
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "oauth2"
            },
                Scheme = "oauth2",
                Name = "oauth2",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
        },
        new List < string > ()
    }});

});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "OutlookEvents v1");

        c.OAuthClientId("xxx");
        c.OAuthClientSecret("xxx");

        c.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

and my appssettings.json looks like this,

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxx.com",
    "TenantId": "xxx",
    "ClientId": "xxx",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "Client secret from app-registration. Check user secrets/azure portal.",
    "ClientCertificates": []
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": [
      "user.read",
      "Calendars.Read",
      "Calendars.ReadWrite",
      "User.Read.All",
      "User.ReadWrite.All",
      "Application.Read.All",
      "Profile"
    ]
  }
}
```

But still am not getting the other user details,may be there is a problem with generation of token.

I need to get valid token with proper scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the [graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) for getting user calendar events.

Since you want to use this api in a web api application and query other users' calendar events, you should use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) for providing authorization and this flow is used for daemon app like console app or web api app. So you need to give application type of api permission `Calendars.Read, Calendars.ReadWrite`.

[image]

[image]

Then use this code in your controller:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var events = await graphClient.Users["xx@xx.onmicrosoft.com"].Calendar.Events.Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: Hii @TinyWang, I used the above code in controller, but still am not getting the result.am getting the error like,        Status Code: NotFound
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ErrorItemNotFound
Message: The specified object was not found in the store.
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:

Comment: could you pls try to use `var user = await graphClient.Users["xx@xx.onmicrosoft.com"].Request().GetAsync()` instead to test if it worked for you? If it succeed, you should get user information as the result. If not, pls change to use another user principle as the parameter...